# How to convert SubjectName and Issuer from XCert license file to a string in C without using OpenSSL function

Tags: c, openssl

In OpenSSL, we have `X509_NAME_oneline` function to convert Issuer and SubjectName to a string

```
char *subj = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), NULL, 0);
char *issuer = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), NULL, 0);
```

But, can anyone please explain the logic of `X509_NAME_oneline` function, so that I could implement it in C without using the built-in function to do the same?

Comment: It's an opensource library. You can simply look at its implementation and write one of your own.